# Почему не проходит валидация?

Tags: php, yii2

Организую загрузку картинок.

**Модель:**

```
class Image extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $files;
     public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [[ 'id_actoutrs', 'id_category', 'id_pages', 'id_serial', 'id_user', 'for_home'], 'integer'],
            [['files'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
            [['title_alt', 'path', 'name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }
```

**Представление:**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'title_alt')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'files[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'for_home')->radioList([
        '0' => Yii::t('app','NO'),
        '1' => Yii::t('app','YES')
    ]); ?>
```

**Контролер:**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Image();
        $class=Yii::$app->request->get("class");
    $feilds =Yii::$app->request->get("feilds");
        $value=Yii::$app->request->get("value");
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->files = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'files');
            foreach ($model->files as $file) {
                $files_to = TransliteratorHelper::process($file->name, '', 'en');
                $years=date('Y');
                $mounts=date('m');
                $path =0;
                switch ($class) {
                    case 'category':
                        $path = 'category';
                        break;
                }
                if (file_exists(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/').$path.'/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/')) {
                } else {
                    mkdir(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/').$path.'/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/', 0775, true);
                }
                $file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/').$path.'/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/'.$files_to);
                $model->path=$path.'/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/';
                $model->name = $files_to;
                $model->save();
            }
```

Дебаг показывает такую ошибку:

> 20:26:09.879 info yii\db\ActiveRecord::insert Model not inserted due to validation error.
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\film.lc\backend\controllers\ImageController.php (98)

`print_r( $model->getErrors())` выдает такую ошибку:

> Array ( [files] => Array ( [0] => Загрузите файл. ) ) 1

В чем проблема?

Comment: Вы валидацию проводите в контроллере. Надо в моделях: https://toster.ru/q/248500

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade    Вопрос это рекомендации или обязательная нотация? Просто там ни где нет объяснений, почему не проходит валидация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если файл не загружается и подразумевается в принципе необязательная загрузка, то попробуйте добавить такой атрибут:

```
[['files'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg','skipOnEmpty' => true ]
```

Comment: загрузка обязательна

Comment: а во-вторых все равно валидация не проходит

Comment: В документации подразумевалась отдельная модель для загрузки файлов, она наследовалась от Model, может в этом дело.

Comment: я уже организовал в той же моделе и ничего

Comment: Ваш совет оказался наиболее правильным его и выбираю.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит указать параметр 'extensions' как массив:

```
[['files'], 'file', 'extensions' => ['png', 'jpg']]
```